# Facebook verbs not updating

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am encountering a problem where when I post to the timeline using verbs, it keeps posting older actions.

So lets say i want to create an action 'want' on a product 'Shoes'

it keeps creating a post i done a while ago 'want' 'jumper'

I have entered test data here but it is still giving me the old 'want' 'jumper' post.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Oh and the verb is still in testing and i have not yet submitted it for approval.

My js is as follows

```
function want() {
    FB.api(
    "/me/appNamespace:Buy?product=http://appUrl/vendor/og/testOgWebsite.aspx",
    'post',
    function (response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            alert( JSON.stringify( response));
        } else {
            alert('Cook was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
        }
    });
}
```

and heres the meta tags on the testOgWebsite page

```
<meta property="og:type" content="appNamespace:Buy">
<meta property="og:title" content="Test">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://appUrl/vendor/og/testOgwebsite.aspx">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.test.com/test.png">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Test">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="137964672905791">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have probably used the same URL for both **Shoes** and **Jumper**.

Every object needs a unique URL.

However, to fix your problem you can use [the Facebook Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to update Facebook's cache of the object.